# Any way I can use a constant number in my program without storing it in memory?

Tags: c, gcc, constants

This is my C code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define SIZE1 500;
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    unsigned long SIZE2=500;
    char astring2[SIZE2];
    char astring[SIZE1];
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the line containing "define" and the line containing `char astring[SIZE1];` then the program will work nicely, however at least 4 bytes in memory are required to store the number 500.

What I'd like to see work which does not work is me removing these two lines instead:

```
unsigned long SIZE2=500;
char astring2[SIZE2];
```

When I compile the complete code above, the compiler gives me these errors:

```
./teststring.c: In function 'main':
./teststring.c:6: error: expected ']' before ';' token
```

This suggests to me that it has a problem with SIZE1. 
I also tried putting quotes around the value of SIZE1 and I still receive the same error.

Is there a way I can do this or am I forced to store a number in memory to use it?

I don't want to constantly type the same number everywhere I need it in my program, so please don't suggest `char astring[500]` as an answer, but it would be nice if the compiler did that behind the scenes for me as it compiles the code to an executable format.

And my compiler is GCC version 4.1.2.

Comment: `define` won't take up any space during runtime.

Comment: That's why I tried it

Comment: Array length is not consuming any memory in the run time. Constant expressions are not consuming any *data* memory, though they might reside in the code (read-only) memory. And such a premature optimization is really obsolete here.

Comment: there are a few problems with the posted code that you should fix first.  1) stdio.h is a system header file.  It should be surrounded by '<' and '>' not by double quotes.   2) when #define'ing numeric values, always surround the values with parens '(' and ')' to avoid text replacement problems.  3) the 2 parameters to main() are unused.  Suggest: 'int main( void )'

Comment: This line: '#define SIZE1 500;'  is not syntactically correct.  A #define is NOT terminated with a semicolon ';'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mean

```
#define SIZE1 500
```

In your code, whenever you use `SIZE1` a semicolon is being inserted. Preprocessor commands like `#define` don't end with semicolons.

Comment: Apparently the system won't let me accept an answer right now, but you fixed the issue

Comment: Yup, there's a delay before it lets you accept. No hurry.